# How to upgrade QT Creator?

Tags: upgrade, qt

I just installed QT Creator 2.4.1 (Based on QT 4.8.0 64bit) from Ubuntu Software Center and noticed that it was not the latest version. How do I upgrade it from terminal? My Ubuntu is 12.0.4LTS.

Thanks.

hc.

Answer (score 11):

The regular ubuntu repositories don't contain the latest version of QT or QT Creator, you will first have to add an ppa via the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

Now you can update:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this doesn't work, try removing QT Creator first and then reinstalling with:

```
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```